# On dispatch Redux Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting error

"Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." with below code

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
state = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

submit = (evt)=>{
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.onAuth(this.state.username,this.state.password)
};

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>

            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'username')}
            />
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'password')}
            />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
return{
    onAuth:(email,password)=> dispatch(actions.auth(email,password))
}
```

};

In actionType.js file :

```
      export const authStart = () => {
            return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_START
 }
 };


       export const auth=(email,password)=>{
return dispatch=>{
    dispatch(authStart())
}
```

};

Initializing the store:

```
    import {createStore} from 'redux'
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
    import CounterReducer from './Containers/store/reducers/counters'

    const RootReducer=CounterReducer;
    const Store=createStore(RootReducer);
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={Store}><App /></Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

On submitting form I am using dispatch, I am new to redux so I am getting problem in finding the issue.

Comment: Is this already solved?

Comment: It was redux thunk issue, was not properly initialized